# How to download Roblox on Gallium OS

Tags: dual-boot, download

So, I've dual booted my chromebook with Chrome OS and Gallium OS. My Chromebook is older, and does not support google play store. I've tried to download Roblox launcher on Chrome OS, and that did not work, as expected. However, on Gallium OS, I have had sucess on downloading things like Blender, and Steam! Is there any way to download Roblox on Gallium OS?

Comment: If you have any idea, it would be greatly appreciated. My other windows based computer does not work for the time being; therefore, I am left with an older Chromebook. I think I even saw "Model version: Toaster" on the back of my Chromebook. Please, Help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no known way to run ROBLOX through any Linux based distro.

You could try methods like installing Windows 7 on a virtual machine and run Roblox through it but there is no way to run Roblox on pure Linux for now.

There is a Roblox alternative though called Finobe.
Finobe is compatible with Linux distros if you use Wine compatibility layer to run it.

https://github.com/LeadRDRK/Winenobe

Comment: Thanks, man, I'll try it out!

Comment: Second thought. Do you know any way I can find a tutorial to download wine? I'm quite unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Roblox probably would run on top of Cloudready which is a Chromium/chromebook OS that does have access to native Linux as well.  The linux built into chromebooks is Debian based. You would have to wipe galliumos though because cloudready is not currently supporting dual boot machines.